# Spark decompression technique using Scala

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to use compression technique in Spark.

```
files1.saveAsSequenceFile("/sequ1", Some(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec]))
```

Now I want to read from compressed file. So I need to decompress it.
How can I do that? Can anyone help me on this?